# Create combinations sets for elements in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a "design of experiments" matrix from a DataFrame that represents the possible choices for each element.

I would like to create a column for each unique combination of elements in a DataFrame, which will represent one experimental set.

Constraints: Elements are not all the same size.

Input:

```
index   Column1 Column2 Column3
 a        a1        
 b        b1      b2       b3
 c        c1      c2    
 d        d1
```

Desired Output:
index   Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6

```
a   a1  a1  a1  a1  a1  a1
b   b1  b2  b3  b1  b2  b3
c   c1  c1  c1  c2  c2  c2
d   d1  d1  d1  d1  d1  d1
```

I have looked at zipping lists but hoping to find an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some itertools action? :-)

```
idx = ['a','b','c','d']
df = pd.DataFrame([['a1',None,None],['b1','b2','b3'],['c1','c2',None],['d1',None,None]], 
                  index=idx,
                  columns=['Column1','Column2','Column3'])
```

[image]

```
NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 6
result = []

for r in df.values:
    #Filter None or other types of "emtpy" values you have:
    filtered = [x for x in r if x is not None]
    # Creat a row by repeating the elements:
    rep_list = list(islice(cycle(filtered), NUM_OF_COLUMNS))
    result.append(rep_list)

res_df = pd.DataFrame(result,
                      index=idx,
                      columns=['Column'+str(i) for i in range(1, NUM_OF_COLUMNS+1)])
```

[image]